# How to retrieve values from multiple rows of the same column in SQL Server

Tags: wpf, listview

I need to search booked patients for the given date. I don"t know what the error in my code is. But I could retrieve only 1 row from the table. Please help

```
string sp = textBox1.Text;

SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection();
con1.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SWATHI-PC\\NM;Initial Catalog=clinic;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=sqlpass";
con1.Open();

string query = "select Booking_dt,Name from patients1 WHERE  Booking_dt=@dt ";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con1);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dt", sp));

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (dr.Read())
{
    listView1.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that it's your

```
if (dr.Read()) { }
```

block only running once.  I don't know the specifics of whichever language you're using, but I'm guessing you need something along the lines of

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    listView1.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString());
}
```

which should iterate through dr.